# R: Load Excel Workbook If it Exists or Create it

Tags: r, excel, error-handling, try-catch, openxlsx

I have a predefined `filename` in my code. I wish to load the file if it exists or create a new workbook if it doesn't. I am trying to do this using `tryCatch` and the package `openxlsx` using the following code:

```
tryCatch({wb <- loadWorkbook(fileName)}, error=function(e){wb <- createWorkbook()})
*some processing*
saveWorkbook(wb, fileName, overwrite = TRUE)
```

My tryCatch doesn't seem to run either of the commands. When I individually run the loadWorkbook it throws an error 'file does not exist', but when I run the tryCatch, it doesn't create a new workbook. Am I using tryCatch in a wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the TryCath is correct, but before saving the Workbook you need to create at least one sheet. Try this:

```
wb <- tryCatch(loadWorkbook(fileName), 
               error = function(e){wb <- createWorkbook(); createSheet(wb, sheetName="Sheet1"); wb})
```

Comment: There is a command in the *processing* part to create a sheet. It is this command which throws an error next saying wb doesn't exist after the tryCatch is run

Comment: Then `wb <- tryCatch(loadWorkbook(fileName), error=function(e){createWorkbook()})` should work, in my pc it works without problem. You must return the wb and create the object outside the TryCath.

Answer (score -1):

Found the issue. 
Since the error part was a function, wb was being created locally in the function. I just had to return wb from the function by assigning it outside the tryCatch as suggested by Juan.

```
wb <- tryCatch({loadWorkbook(fileName)}, error=function(e){createWorkbook()})
*some processing*
saveWorkbook(wb, fileName, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: This does not work, you must assign the WorkBook outside the TryCath as in my example.